# What different between WebRequest's GetReponse and WebRequest's BeginGetResponse in C#?

Tags: c#

I need know that file is exist in patch sever. Because I want to check assetbundles are exist in server. If file is not exist, app will not download assetbundles from server.

So I searched the internet I found WebRequest's `GetResponse` and `BeginGetResponse`.

MSDN let me know `BeginGetResponse` is `async` function. I think BeginGetResponse is faster than GetResponse. So I want to use BeginGetResponse.  but I can't check file exist from server when I use BeginGetResponse. I can check only `GetResponse`.

What is the differences between WebRequest's `GetReponse` and WebRequest's `BeginGetResponse` in .NET?

Comment: `BeginGetResponse` was pre C# 5.0 and should be avoided as it is much more complex as compared to [`GetResponseAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.getresponseasync?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Net_WebRequest_GetResponseAsync). Prefer that.

Comment: You're not asking the question you want answered. Do you want to know the difference between these methods, or do you want to check if a resource exists at a given URL?

Comment: Your question in current form is not very clear. Please reformat your question and do not include multiple questions in one post.

Comment: You would use BeginGetResponse if you want to monitor the progress of the download (useful if you need to provide progress meter etc).

Comment: `HttpWebRequest` will throw an exception for a response `StatusCode` > 399. This is how it works. You have to handle the exception. If you don't know how/don't want to, use [`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx). It will handle the exception for you and you'll just have to inspect the `StatusCode` to see if the resource is not found (404).

Comment: My question's intend is I want to know WebRequest's GetReponse and WebRequest's BeginGetResponse in .NET. I already check file exist in server use GetResponse.

Comment: Thank you guys especially jimi. I found solution. I check exception. It work.